# auto save to db in ruby camping web app

Tags: ruby, ajax, forms, web-applications, camping

I need help with the form submission and saving to db in my ruby camping web app.

The app itself is a quality assurance app. Users fill in forms for any errors detected during the quality check. The problem is that the check can take for a couple of hours or in extreme cases even more. During that time, in order to save the data, users have to submit the form several times. Currently I've set it up so that the users submit the form and are immediately redirected back to the form.

How would I go about to enable some sort of autosaving, let's say every 10 minutes or upon each change to the form so users don't have to do it manually.

This is quite difficult for me because I'm not a programmer per say, butI learn as go alogn to optimize my processes.

I've been reading about ajax and jquery but I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction since I don't know where to start and camping examples are rather scarce.

---

EDIT

Some additional infos:

I've successfully implemented jQuery to my camping app and I can manipulate html elements, but AJAX doesn't work. Firebug console doesn't return any errors.

Here are my assumptions:

If the form can be successfully submitted manually I don't have to change anything in my controller or view in order for AJAX to work, right?

The url passed to AJAX doesn't have to include the object id for which I want to submitt the form, right? I'm passing the '/edit' url and the full url to the relevant object is for example '/edit/5'.

Here is the code from the html head:

```
    script :type => 'text/javascript' do "
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#np').change(function() {
          $('#add_form').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/edit',
              data: $('#add_form').serialize(),
            });
          });
        });

        $('#search_indiv_form').click(function(){
          $('#search_indiv_form_toggle').toggle(700);
        });

      });"
    end
```

Are there any errors in my ajax code to prevent the form being submitted?

thank you.
regards,
seba

Comment: Have a Javascript timer that ticks every 10 minutes that sends a HTTP POST request asynchronously (called AJAX) to your server that saves it.

Comment: Would this go to my controller? And since I'm not using Rails where I believe this is more automated, is there an approximate example you could provide as a reference?

Comment: I made a wrong assumption about the controller, I have to work from my views. I'll try to trigger ajax with jQuery in my view.